# Is there an algorithm to decide whether or not two algebraic surfaces are birationally equivalent?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

It needn't be constructive, in the sense of producing a birational map between the surfaces, although that would be a "nice to have".

It appears the Minimal Model of a surface ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_model_program ) is pretty much unique (aside from a slight elaboration in one case, according to that article).

So I guess the question, for surfaces, amounts to asking if there is an algorithm, in Mathematica or Sage for example, for determining the Minimal Model of a specified algebraic surface.

edit: If it makes a difference, I mean equivalent over Q, i.e. the surfaces and birational maps must have only rational coefficients.

Comment: IMHO, it makes no sense to ask about an algorithm without specifying the desired input.

Comment: Over the rationals, as in your edit, it's bad. We don't even know how to do this for curves of genus one without assuming finiteness of the Tate-Shafarevich group. You might have better luck over the algebraic numbers. I don't know if an issue arises for elliptic surfaces, since the problem is slightly different as a birational map may not preserve the fibration.

Comment: If you're going to invoke the minimal model program, you should allow complex coefficients.

Comment: I'm not convinced by your minimal model program suggestion.  Suppose we have two minimal surfaces--is there an algorithm that decides whether or not they are isomorphic?  I think I have a solution if they have polyhedral nef cones, but in general...

Comment: If you have two canonically polarized surfaces with the same Hilbert polynomial, you can "check" whether they are geometrically isomorphic by using invariant theory, I think. First, you consider them as points on the same Hilbert scheme (with coordinates inside some Grassmannian). Then, basically, you write down "equations" for the action of the group PGL$_n$ (some appropriate $n$)...

Comment: ...This is where you will have to use some invariant theory probably. Then,  you check whether these points are in the same orbit; here you really need the full force of invariant theory. You can probably do something similar with surfaces of general type (not necessarily canonically polarized).